# Change class of a div when parent is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

My problem/question is actually related to two problems that I could not find a solution.

This is the div on the "normal" state (without hover or selected). When the user select this div, it change to a purple border. My problem is: **How do I change the class of the icon (that blue icon) when the parent gets selected?**

Normal State:

[image]

Hover State (Icon) / Selected State (Parent Div)

[image]

**Another problem: All the divs with the icon is the same class. I tried one code and it worked, but all .icon divs is also selected (there is 4 divs, when I select one, it selects all the divs)**

This is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/905hut4v/ (the results tab will not work, since I have to copy and paste all the code from the project and I think I cannot [becase a NDA]). I'm using Foundation 6, that's why there is include error on the SCSS.

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('form[name="form-jeitos"] .block-jeito').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    $('.image-icon').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings().toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('form[name="form-jeitos"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("hide");
        $('#jeito-title').addClass("hide");
        var checked = $('input:checked', $(this));
        $('#'+checked.val()).siblings().removeClass("is-active");
        $('#'+checked.val()).addClass("is-active");
    });

    $('#jeito-opcoes a.back').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#jeito-opcoes .is-active').removeClass("is-active");
        $('form[name="form-jeitos"]').removeClass("hide");
        $('#jeito-title').removeClass("hide");
    });

});
```

**SCSS**

```
.block-jeito {
    border: 2px solid rgba(1, 33, 105, 0.1);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 30px 38px 30px 38px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;

    .image-icon {
        position: relative;

        .img {
            @include breakpoint(medium) {
                margin-left: -10px;
            }
        }

    }

    .icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        background-color: #1155CC;
        padding: 20px;
        left: 45%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        max-height: 75px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

        &:hover,
        &.selected {
            background-color: #00C7B1;
        }

        @include breakpoint(xsmall) {
            padding: 20px;
            left: 45%;
            top: 35%;
        }

        @include breakpoint(xxsmall) {
            padding: 20px;
            left: 45%;
            top: 35%;
        }

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
            padding: 20px;
            left: 25%;
            top: 45%;
        }

        @include breakpoint(xmedium) {
            padding: 15px;
            left: 55%;
            top: 45%;
        }

        @include breakpoint(large) {
            padding: 10px;
            left: 65%;
            top: 45%;
        }

        @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
            top: 45%;
            left: 55%;
            padding: 15px;
        }
    }

    &:hover,
    &.selected {
        border: 2px solid #5F249F;
    }

    &.hide {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-weight: 400;

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        strong {
            font-weight: 700;
        }

    }

    img {

        margin-bottom: 50px;

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

    }

}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form name="form-jeitos">

  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

    <label id="codigo-block"
           class="cell labl small-12 medium-6 block-jeito align-middle">

      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

        <div class="cell small-12 large-4 image-icon">
          <img src="../assets/img/foto-codigo.png" class="img"
               alt="Imagem de código e programação, representando a Nordware">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="../assets/img/icon-codigo.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell small-12 large-8">
          <input type="radio" name="opcoes" value="teste-nordware"
                 checked="checked"/>
          <p><strong>Código e programação</strong> é comigo mesmo!</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </label>

    <label id="estrategia-block"
           class="cell labl small-12 medium-6 block-jeito align-middle">

      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

        <div class="image-icon" class="cell small-12 large-4">
          <img src="../assets/img/foto-estrategia.png" class="img"
               alt="Adoro trabalhar com estratégias, pessoas e processos.">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="../assets/img/icon-estrategia.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell small-12 large-8">
          <input type="radio" name="opcoes" value="teste-proxys"/>
          <p>Adoro trabalhar com <strong>estratégias, pessoas e
            processos.</strong></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </label>

    <label id="tecnologia-block"
           class="cell labl small-12 medium-6 block-jeito align-middle">

      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

        <div class="image-icon" class="cell small-12 large-4">
          <img src="../assets/img/foto-tecnologia.png" class="img"
               alt="Imagem de tecnologia e notebooks, representando a BringII">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="../assets/img/icon-tecnologia.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell small-12 large-8">
          <input type="radio" name="opcoes" value="teste-bringit"/>
          <p>Gosto de novidades, do mundo de <strong>tecnologia e
            notebooks.</strong></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </label>

    <label id="mobilidade-block"
           class="cell labl small-12 medium-6 block-jeito align-middle">

      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

        <div class="image-icon" class="cell small-12 large-4">
          <img src="../assets/img/foto-mobilidade.png" class="img"
               alt="Imagem de tecnologia e notebooks, representando a BringII">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="../assets/img/icon-mobilidade.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell small-12 large-8">
          <input type="radio" name="opcoes" value="teste-mobiz"/>
          <p>Seja carro, moto ou bike, eu curto é <strong>mobilidade.</strong>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </label>

    <div class="cell small-12">

      <button type="submit" class="button">Conferir Resultados</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

By the way, if you are wondering why there is another two functions on the javascript: When the user select a div and click the submit button, we 'redirect' the user to another page (we actually just unhide a div).

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the switching of icon images upon parent div focus with CSS selectors, no need to use JavaScript.

A minimal example:

```css
.outer {
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.outer .nofocus {
  display: inline;
}

.outer .focus {
  display: none;
}

.outer:focus .nofocus {
  display: none;
}

.outer:focus .focus {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Click inside the box:</p>
<div class="outer" tabindex="0">
  <div class="icon">
    <img class="nofocus" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/841/60/60.jpg?hmac=O4KlxA1-OGoNAFLLbula_vD6LrmU4H-l-yD5kkXpmLI">
    <img class="focus" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/453/60/60.jpg?hmac=prDxZwonQi-meeXg_btjnTrjJKw5Crr85tpKIiCP_6E">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @terrymorse, thanks for the help! I actually solved this with the help from a senior front-end at the company :) I left my answer unchecked since your answer also helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve this myself, I actually got help from a senior front-end.

What he said it was: the JS was putting the selected in both divs (in the main div and also in the child div).

So the problem was not really JS, but CSS!

This is how we solved:

```
&:hover,
&.selected {
  border: 2px solid #5F249F;
    
  .icon {
    background-color: #00C7B1;
  }
}
```